# Primefaces remotecommand action called only once

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have

```
<p:remoteCommand name="updateSelectedTarget" update="partToUpdate" actionListener="#{bean.onSelectedTarget}"/>
```

bean.java

```
public void onSelectedTarget() {
    System.out.println("here");
}
```

With this configuration, the action is only fired once. Do I need to use actionListener or action? And is there something to do with the process parameter of remoteCommand?

I just want to add that it was working before. I just changed the updated part below

```
<h:panelGroup id="partToUpdate" layout="block">
    <p:panelGrid rendered="#{bean.selectedTarget == null ? false : true}">
        ...
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.stuffID}">
            ...
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        ...
    </p:panelGrid>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Before there was just an ID one the selectOneMenu

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.stuffID}">
```

and now I have the object

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.stuff}">
```

Comment: I pretty sure there is something with the use of a converter with selectOneMenu but I can't make it works.

Comment: What should the remoteCommand actually do? Where in the xhtml are you defining remoteCommand? Are you getting any errors (JavaScript or Java)? Can you see an ajax request going out in the browsers network log?

Comment: The remoteCommand should update my page to display or not a part of the page. So the action change an attribute of my bean and my page has a component that render only if this attribute is true. remoteCommand is defined at the end of the page and I haven't Java errors or Javascripts error in chrome's console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the java.lang.ClassCastException comes from the line

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel="None" itemValue="null" />
```

Could you verify this

Comment: Nope.. Same without. I must be on the conversion itself like if the converter was not recognized.

Comment: In fact you were right! But I had also this problem where the ItemValue must be an object and not the Id `<f:selectItems value="#{bean.allusers}" var="user" itemValue="#{user}" itemLabel="#{user.name}"/>` The last thing is how to set a default null value if I couldn't set it this way?

Comment: Because `<f:selectItem itemLabel="None" noSelectionOption="true">` or `<f:selectItem itemLabel="None" itemValue="#{null}" />` is giving me a NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

```
@FacesConverter("user")
public class UserConverter implements Converter{

    private List<User> users;

    public UserConverter(){
        this.users = myController.getAllUsers();
    }

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        return this.getUser(value);
    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        return String.valueOf(((User) value).getId()).toString();
    }


    public User getUser(String id) {
        Iterator<User> iterator = this.users.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
           User user = iterator.next();

           if(user.getId() == Integer.valueOf(id)) {
               return user;
           }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I think my converter is good because I use it somewhere else.
Maybe the mistake is how to use it with the h:selectOneMenu

I have this

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedUser}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="None" itemValue="null" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.allusers}" var="user" itemValue="#{user.id}" itemLabel="#{user.name}"/>
    <f:converter converterId="user"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: And with this I have this error `juil. 16, 2013 11:57:20 AM com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback visit
SEVERE: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.dto.User`

Answer (score 0):

So to conclude I changed my selectOneMenu to

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedUser}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="None" itemValue="#{null}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.allusers}" var="user" itemValue="#{user}" itemLabel="#{user.name}"/>
    <f:converter converterId="user"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

And in my converter

```
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    if(!StringUtils.isInteger(value)) {
        return null;
    }
    return this.getUser(value);
}

public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    if(value == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return String.valueOf(((User) value).getId()).toString();
}
```

With the method below because I am looking for id and getAsObject value returned the label "None"

```
public static boolean isInteger(String s) {
    try { 
        Integer.parseInt(s); 
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
        return false; 
    }
    return true;
}
```

And problem solved.
Thnks

**EDIT**

Don't forget to add the equals override method to the User class.

Answer (score -1):

it happens to me many times like this and I find that the problem comes from previous page that call the current one

Comment: Thnks for your help but I really think it's about the selectOneMenu now because when I remove it, the action is called.